# Trying to create an array of duplicate values from another array, why doesn't my code work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I am working on this piece of code here where the goal is to create an array of all the values that are duplicated from another array. The resulting array I'd like to have should only enter the duplicated values from the first array once. **The catch is I can't use any array functions or methods**. This is what I have so far:

```
var numbers = [8,24,20,5,13,3,1,12,11,24,8,24,20,4,5,23,24,23,21,2,19,3,21,2,14,17,21,5,7,10,20,11,0,5,18,2,13,11,14,3,20,1,23,6,21,10,14,0,15,20];

var results = [];
var tempArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
  if (tempArr[numbers[i]] === undefined) {
    tempArr[numbers[i]] = 1;
  } else if (results[numbers[i]] === undefined)  {
    results.push(numbers[i]);
  }
}

console.log(tempArr);
console.log(results);
```

I am getting closer to me desired output… but for some reason the results array continues to contain multiple entries of the values that are duplicated in the numbers array. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Just to be clear, you cannot use any of these methods https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp? It seems to me you are using `.push()` there...?

Comment: Hmm, good question.  Well, I guess the idea is to not use methods to manipulate the array to find the duplicates.  I think filling the array with the found duplicates with `.push()` would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically abusing an array as an object. Try using an object instead to log your values (and give said object a name that represents what it holds), it'll greatly simplify your code:

```js
var numbers = [8,24,20,5,13,3,1,12,11,24,8,24,20,4,5,23,24,23,21,2,19,3,21,2,14,17,21,5,7,10,20,11,0,5,18,2,13,11,14,3,20,1,23,6,21,10,14,0,15,20];

var results = [];
var seenValues = {};

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  const number = numbers[i];
  seenValues[number] = 1 + (seenValues[number] || 0);
  // check to see if it's been seen exactly once before,
  // so that the duplicated value is only added once:
  if (seenValues[number] === 2) results[results.length] = number;
}

//console.log(seenValues);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Just small note: `<=` should also be changed to `<`, as the length is always +1 compared to the index.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Oh right, `push` counts too I suppose. Well, easy to assign to `results[results.length]` instead

Comment: All good - its surprising how far we go to help with homework - no one other than a professor would come up with this silliness.